# Exception in Python breaks for loop despite putting in continue/pass

Tags: python

Im writing a python code that loops file directories and sub-directories to extract word doc file and write the content of word doc to excel/csv files. If some files are invalid (for example they have XML, the loop would skip)

The issue now is I managed to get it more or less working, but for some reason, my for loop is breaking, and I can't continue.

So for example: In this file path, I have 6 word documents. 1 of these documents is not valid because it is a XML file. The rest of the 5 word documents are valid and I expect 5 file content to be saved into a csv file. However, in my current final.csv, I only have 4 word doc content being saved into the csv file. I can only assume that when the exception happens it does not continue. However, I already placed a pass inside my exception.

Is my understanding not correct in which pass does not continue the loop?

My code looks like this below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import docx2txt
import csv
import re
import os

def read_files():
    
    
    list_of_lists = []

    full_path =""
    rootdir = '/Users/xxx/Documents/github/xxxx/xxxxx/Financial Statements/'
    
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
            try:
                for file in files:
                    print(os.path.join(subdir, file))

                    content = [" "] * 22
                    
                    if file.endswith(".docx") or file.endswith(".doc"):
                        full_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
                        print(full_path)
                        text = docx2txt.process(full_path)
                        s = " "
                        for line in text.splitlines():
                        #This will ignore empty/blank lines. 
                            if line != '':
                                s = s+ " " + line
                                s = s.replace(",", "")
                                s = " ".join(s.split())
                                s = s.strip()
                        content.insert(6, s)
                        content.insert(0, subdir)
                        content.insert(1, file)
                        list_of_lists.append(content)
                    else:
                        print("AAAA")
                #print(list_of_lists)

                
            except Exception as error:
                
                print(full_path)
                f = open("exception.txt", "a")
                f.write(full_path + "\n")
                f.write(str(error) + "\n")
                f.close()
                print("An exception occurred", error)
                pass
                
            finally:
                df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists)
                #print(df)
                df.to_csv('final.csv', encoding='utf-8')


read_files()
```

Comment: Your `try-except` is outside of the `for file in files` loop, so that loop ends prematurely on the first error within that directory.

Comment: Ah Thank you no wonder! got it working now.

Comment: `pass` does not have any function besides providing indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your search looks very complicated. Try this one, endswith() takes a tupel and os.walk knows topdown:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.', topdown=True):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(('.doc', '.docx')):
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
```